# What's the maximum time can servlet execute in background?(Servlet timeout)

Tags: java, curl, get, timeout, servlet-3.0

I have written a Java servlet that in the `doGet` I have made Thread.sleep(1000 * 60 * 60*5) to wait for 5 hour and then using the curl I will invoke this servlet using --max-time 999999.

What is the maximum servlet timeout and is there any thing related in the servlet 3.0 specification?

Comment: There is no maximum time. But there are **many** timeouts between your code and Curl's code. There is a socket timeout at the protocol level, at the connection level and potentially at the harware level. There may also be proxies along the way that have similar timeouts. Essentially, you cannot assume anything and have to gracefully handle disconnection and resumption of long running requests.

Comment: I'm using TCP/IP so which socket timeout you are speaking about?

Comment: Well, I assume so - what else would you be using? That's the problem - _all of them_... (including ones on proxy servers in the middle, ones on switches and hubs along the route, ones on routers and NATs across networks)

Comment: there is nothing on what you are talking about (no firewall,no NAT....) i'm using it locally

Comment: Then you have all the timeouts across loopback - but there are obviously fewer to deal with.

Comment: Servlet 3.0 don't have something like timeout?